# Fallo al al intentar subir una imagen codificada al una base de datos mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Intento subir un imagen codificada que almaceno un varible extrayéndola de otra de base de datos que almaceno en una varible codificándola con base64_encode.

Obtengo la imagen.

```
$_SESSION['IMAGEN'][$id]=base64_encode($registro['IMAGEN']);
```

La quiero almacenar en otra base de datos, la codifico mediante base64_decode.

```
$IMAGEN=base64_decode($_SESSION['IMAGEN'][$x]);
```

Resulta que da un fallo al realizar la consulta.

```
$consulta_articulos="INSERT INTO pedido_contiene (ID_PEDIDO, ID_ARTICULO, CANTIDAD, TITULO1, TITULO2, PRECIO,IMAGEN)
        VALUES ";

        foreach($_SESSION['ID'] as $x => $valor)
        {   
            $ID=$_SESSION['ID'][$x];
            $CANTIDAD=$_SESSION['CANTIDAD'][$x];
            $TITULO1=$_SESSION['TITULO1'][$valor];
            $TITULO2=$_SESSION['TITULO2'][$valor];
            $PRECIO=$_SESSION['PRECIO'][$x];
            $IMAGEN=base64_decode($_SESSION['IMAGEN'][$x]);

            $consulta_articulos=$consulta_articulos."($id_pedido,'$ID',$CANTIDAD,'$TITULO1','$TITULO2',$PRECIO,'$IMAGEN'),";            
        }
        echo $IMAGEN;
```

1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '\0010' at line 2

Comment: lo mejor es dejarlo todo codificado a base 64, no entiendo por que la decodificas, bueno lo mejor es codificarlo a base 64 y comprimir los datos pero es cosa de cada quien, si son datos binarios debes guardarlos como tal [un vistaso aqui](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asumiendo que no hay problema en cuanto al contenido que estás obteniendo, nombres de tabla y columnas, etc, tu problema estaría en esta parte de tu bucle:

```
        $consulta_articulos=$consulta_articulos."($id_pedido,'$ID',$CANTIDAD,'$TITULO1','$TITULO2',$PRECIO,'$IMAGEN'),";
```

En cada iteracción, estarías agregando esto:

```
$consulta_articulos="INSERT INTO pedido_contiene (ID_PEDIDO, ID_ARTICULO, CANTIDAD, TITULO1, TITULO2, PRECIO,IMAGEN)
```

Produciendo al final una instrucción SQL errónea. Bastaría con hacer un `echo $consulta_articulos;` al final de todo para comprobar que tu instrucción es errónea desde el punto de vista sintáctico.

Para evitar ese error de sintaxis tú debes crear una instrucción SQL que sea correcta, aunque lo propio aquí sería usar consultas preparadas, si quieres evitar riesgos de *inyección SQL*, pero ese es otro tema, el cual sin embargo no deberías ignorar.

Para evitar el error de sintaxis puedes hacer esto:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO pedido_contiene (ID_PEDIDO, ID_ARTICULO, CANTIDAD, TITULO1, TITULO2, PRECIO,IMAGEN)
        VALUES ";
$values="";
#Determinamos el último índice del array
$lastKey = array_key_last($_SESSION['ID']);
foreach($_SESSION['ID'] as $x => $valor) {
    $ID=$_SESSION['ID'][$x];
    $CANTIDAD=$_SESSION['CANTIDAD'][$x];
    $TITULO1=$_SESSION['TITULO1'][$valor];
    $TITULO2=$_SESSION['TITULO2'][$valor];
    $PRECIO=$_SESSION['PRECIO'][$x];
    $IMAGEN=base64_decode($_SESSION['IMAGEN'][$x]);
    $values.="($id_pedido,'$ID',$CANTIDAD,'$TITULO1','$TITULO2',$PRECIO,'$IMAGEN')";    
    #Si es el último índice, agregamos ; de lo contrario agregamos ,       
    if($x == $lastKey) {
        $values.=";";         
    } else {
        $values.=",";
    }
}
$sql.=$values;
echo $sql;
```

Aquí `$sql` tendrá este formato más o menos, el cual es totalmente válido:

```
INSERT INTO pedido_contiene 
(ID_PEDIDO, ID_ARTICULO, CANTIDAD, TITULO1, TITULO2, PRECIO,IMAGEN)
VALUES
    (1,'1',1,'Título11','Título21',1,'imagen1'),
    (2,'2',2,'Título12','Título22',2,'imagen2'),
    (3,'3',3,'Título13','Título23',3,'imagen3');
```

#### Nota:

`array_key_last()` usado más arriba para obtener el valor del último elemento del array, fue introducido en PHP 7.3. Si tu versión de PHP es anterior, puedes sustituirlo por esto:

```
$arrayKeys = array_keys($_SESSION['ID']);
$lastKey = array_pop($arrayKeys);
```

Comment: Ya funciona he añadido un  addslashes a la imagen .